# Angular insecure url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jcrop

I'm using this directive to use jCrop with Angular:  http://plnkr.co/edit/Z2IQX8s9UK6wQ1hS4asz?p=preview

When I load in a value for `src`, I get this error:

> Can't interpolate: {{profileImg}} Error: [$sce:insecurl]

Then it links me to a page that says this:

> Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.

My html is this:

```
<img-cropped src={{profileImg}} selected='selected(cords)'/>
```

And this error happens when I change `$scope.profileImg` to the url of my image.

I'm linking to S3, where I get the value from `profileImg`. I trust this source, so how can I tell angular that this source is trusted enough to get this directive working?

If I hardcode the `src` to be my image, I don't get this problem.

### EDIT:

I'm trying to trust the url with $sce.

My controller:

```
cmsApp.controller('PresentationCtrl',function($scope, $upload, all, $sce){

var socket = io.connect('https://xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx:3000');
$scope.profileImg="";



$scope.uploadProfilePic = function(){
    socket.removeAllListeners();
    console.log(file3);
    var url = 'https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxx:3000/uploadProfile?tenant=xxxxx';

    $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url:url,
        data:{myObj:'test1'},
        file:file3
    }).progress(function(evt){
        console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        $sce.trustAsUrl(data);
        $scope.profileImg = data;
    });
};
});
```

And even with the `trustAsUrl`, it throws the same error.

It might be that I'm trying to connect from it from my local nginx server?

### EDIT2:

I moved it to S3 hosting, and it worked. The image I'm trying to link to is also on S3.
I moved it to an Apache web server on an EC2 instance, and it didn't work.

I'm using all the answers, `ng-src` instead of `src`, `$sce.trustAsUrl(url)`, and the `$compileProvider`

Comment: Have you tried ng-src instead of src on the img? It should help prevent similar problems. The fact that hard coding it works tells me that you should probably use ng-src instead.

Comment: @aaronfrost I just tried that, and it didn't work. I get the same errrors

Comment: In your controller where you are setting the url, you need to inject the $sce service, and use it. Not sure what is going wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: @aaronfrost I posted my controller code, and it looks like I injected `$sce`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sometimes its good to read the docs about [$sce](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce)

This is a alternative to whitelist all blob and data:image/* urls for just the `<img>` tag but there is other way that you can solve this like generate a url > pass it into one of the sce function and it will be whitelisted. like @NuclearGhost said

```
app.config(["$compileProvider" function($compileProvider) {

    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(blob:|data:image)/);

}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to add the url as a trusted source you can use the `trustAsUrl()` method from `ng.$sce` service

Here's the [angular documentation for the service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce#methods_trustasresourceurl).

Comment: I tried typing `ng.$sce.trustAsUrl(url)` and that told me that `ng` was not defined.

Comment: You need to inject `$sce` as a service into your controller or directive where you're making the http call from.  Then just access it from `$sce.trustAsUrl(url)`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just turning it off with `$sceProvider.enabled(false)`.

Comment: I don't think it was a good idea. You could have set a trusted (white-listed) URL instead using [`$sceDelegateProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider#resourceUrlWhitelist)