# Applying image blob to src in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, blob, src

I have some API endpoints which provide images, but said images require authentication. I have a service (`authenticatedHttp`) which is an abstraction over $http and handles the authentication token management. (This is confirmed to be working, and for all intents and purposes might as well be `$http`)

I am receiving the response, getting a blob and creating an object URL. All of this works. I have checked the blob and can confirm it is correct.

The problem comes in when I try to apply `objectUrl` to `src`. I have tried a simplified example using a snippet I know works and no authentication. This does not work in my Angular app, but does work in vanilla JS.

I don't know much about `ObjectUrl` but if it makes a difference, when I inspect the empty image I see that it's `src` is correct, and that if I click the link created (ex. `blob:https://sub.domain.dev/de4db0e0-77c8-44bc-a934-0d270ab81687`) I get redirected by `ui-router`.

Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

```
app.directive('authenticatedSrc', ['authenticatedHttp', function (authenticatedHttp) {
  var directive = {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'A'
  };
  return directive;
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var requestConfig = {
      cache: 'false'
    };
    authenticatedHttp.get(attrs.authenticatedSrc, requestConfig).then(function(response) {
      var objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], { type: 'image/png' }));
      attrs.$set('src', objectUrl);
    });
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Please for the future, if you want proper help, notice the tagging, angular-tag refers to angular <=2, you should have used angularjs. This time I fixed it for you ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 My bad, Thanks.

Comment: This tutorial will help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: Object URLs point to objects that are local to the browser e.g. blob URLs data URLs. Remove blob: in the beginning of https.

Comment: @bhantol I tried that. I just get redirected by ui-router.

Comment: @AlonEitan I just implemented what is described there. I got the exact same result.

Comment: @AlonEitan I just console logged the result...it looks like that base64 encoded the image and then stuck it in src as data with the correct MIME and encoding type. I have tried that manually. Still results in an empty image, however I can see it just fine in Postman or other REST client as plain binary.

Comment: You've got to add blobURI and dataURI scheme as whitelisted in url sanitizer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular insecure url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735002/angular-insecure-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kaiido was correct also, but it was not my main problem.

@georgeawg solved the majority of my problem, but I did not accept his answer because his implementation (using the blob directly as the source) did not work for me.

This is my final code which works.

```
app.directive('authenticatedSrc', ['authenticatedHttp', function (authenticatedHttp) {
  var directive = {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'A'
  };
  return directive;
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var requestConfig = {
      cache: 'false',
      responseType: 'blob'
    };
    authenticatedHttp.get(attrs.authenticatedSrc, requestConfig).then(function(response) {
      var reader = new window.FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(response.data);
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        attrs.$set('src', reader.result);
      };
    });
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When downloading binary information, it is important to set the `responseType`:

```
app.directive('authenticatedSrc', ['authenticatedHttp', function (authenticatedHttp) {
  var directive = {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'A'
  };
  return directive;
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var requestConfig = {
      //IMPORTANT
      responseType: 'blob',
      cache: 'false'
    };
    authenticatedHttp.get(attrs.authenticatedSrc, requestConfig).then(function(response) {
      //var objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], { type: 'image/png' }));
      var blob = response.data;
      attrs.$set('src', blob);
    });
  }
}]);
```

Otherwise the data gets corrupted by conversion from [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) to [DOMstring (UTF-16)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString).

For more information, see [MDN XHR API ResponseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType).

Answer (score 0):

What is the return type of response.data? Is it a base64 encoded string? 
Img tag can very well render base64 encoded images when provided directly in the src attribute.
Moreover, please try $sce service of angularjs to trust this objectUrl as a valid Url. $sce.trustAsURL(objectUrl) while adding to src attribute.
More info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: It's binary. But Postman displays it just fine. I've converted to base64 and tried it that way, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Please give a shot a $sce and check if it renders the image. Do you see empty box or a image not found icon?

Comment: Yes. It displays the "image not found".